# Flutter - The emulator is not working properly

Tags: android-studio, debugging, flutter, dart, android-emulator

Changing the code and debugging the emulator also applies the previously used code and the emulator works.

I don't know what the problem is, but the updated code doesn't apply to the emulator and the code I used before runs.

I will be very grateful if you give me an answer or a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the command `flutter clean` to remove the existing build output and run your app.